# about json file direction?

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, response

in jquery.subgrid.js --> for json request  this term **$.parse(JSON.responseText)** showing undefined.

what return JSON.responseText????

Answer (score 0):

JSON.responseText is the text returned by the server.